# Built-in iSight not working after migrating OS X from Mac Mini to MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, webcam

Used Migration Assistant to migrate from Mac Mini (which is without iSight) to MacBook Pro (which has iSight). MacBook Pro was installed with OS X 10.6, then Software Update(d) to 10.6.8, before downloading Lion installer from Mac App Store.

What I've checked so far
 - iSight camera is not detected by iChat, Photo Booth, Skype.
 - System Profiler does not detect Camera under list of USB device
 - There are AppleUSBDevices framework installed at the default location
   with proper file permissions

I've also read through Google search results dating from 2006 to 2011.

Comment: We'll need more information to help you.  Can you say more about "not working" - specifically, what things you have tried that don't work?  When you run applications that uses the iSight, PhotoBooth f/ex, does the iSight LED light up, and what do you see in the video window? Does System Profiler show a "Built-in iSight" in the USB section?  Did the iSight work at any of the update stages you mentioned?  Has it ever worked?

Comment: Hi JRobert, you're absolutely right. I've added more info in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adding update for posterity and closing this question]

Pleased to report my iSight was working in my MBP with a new logic board.